# Is there a word or idiom for the phemonon of conflating the definition of a word with its connotation

Tags: idiom-requests

Suppose that a person(Person A) gets attacked, and they kill their assailant in self defense.

Another person(Person B) who this considers killing to be bad, but they consider this specific circumstance to be justified, therefore, they say that the Person A did not kill.

This is wrong, because the definition of "kill" does not have an exception for when it is justified.

Is there a term for the kind of fallacy where someone affirms or denies a label to something because of an emotional reaction, and not because of the actual meaning of the label?

Comment: I don't understand. "Cowardly" *is* inherently a "bad" label, so on that one you just seem to be saying it's being ***misused*** (if we allow that suicide bombers are actually "brave", which is debatable). For your other two examples, it all depends on the speaker and his intended audience - what they understand by the words "socialism" or "feminism", *and* whether they see these as positive or negative terms. To many people, "moderation" and "censorship" can mean the same thing, the choice of word depending on whether or not they *agree* with what's actually being moderated/censored.

Comment: `I don't understand. "Cowardly" is inherently a "bad" label, so on that one you just seem to be saying it's being misused`  I do know an idiom for the logical fallacy that you just used.  It's called "Affirming the consequent", and you did it when you assumed that  "cowardly implies bad" means the same thing as "bad implies cowardly"(they're not the same).

Comment: I never remotely suggested that *bad* implies *cowardly*. Your question asks about people applying the word *cowardly* to terrorists even if those terrorists don't fit your definition of the word. Which is completely different to your *socialist, feminist* examples, since in those cases there doesn't seem to be a *semantic* issue in play - merely the fact that different people ascribe difference positive/negative associations to the terms. Nobody is ambivalent about whether *cowards* are positive or negative.

Comment: I think a better example would help clear up your question. Terrorists are bad, cowardly is bad, and "terrorists are cowardly" in no way implies that terrorists are cowardly because all bad things are cowardly.

Comment: @Kevin there are multiple examples,  such as `It's not socialist to regulate the food industry because bad food can make people sick`, which is probably a more clear example.  The "terrorists are cowards" example exists because mote people will recognize that one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the word 'cowardly' word can be that subjective, and defined solely on the positive/negative feelings toward the word and the action, then that was a cowardly comment that you just made.

Comment: @Sam: The "meaning" of the word *socialist* in your food example is so vague you might as well say it's just being used as a synonym for ***good***. It strikes me as a weird thiing to say in the first place, but it could *only* make sense if both the speaker and his target audience accept that anything which is "socialist" is also by definition "good" (not necessarily that they are synonyms, simply that anything correctly labelled "socialist" must *by definition* also be "good").

Comment: Like @FumbleFingers, I feel like there is no more specific label for this phenomenon than 'mistake'. i.e. "You have used the wrong word, and here is why" followed by analysis. It sounds similar to 'malapropism' (the wrong word which sounds like the one you should have used) but rather using the wrong meaning word that only shares connotation. Would another example be possibly "Politicians are ugly" (because in some instances they show anger in public and that can be ugly)? Maybe the problem is 'fallacy of ambiguity' ?

Comment: @Mitch: I think unless you're a *seriously* disaffected citizen, you wouldn't be likely to say *Politicians are ugly* except as a "sweeping generalization" (regardless of exactly what "ugly" would be supposed to mean there, one thing we can be pretty sure of is that any such speaker and his target audience all agree that being ugly is a bad thing). But it's hardly a sweeping generalization to say that Women in CS aren't feminists because they don't seek to exclude men. I don't know what it *is* (bonkers?, muddy thinking?), but it's not a "generalization".

Comment: @FumbleFingers If I follow you (I'm not at all sure that I do; I don't get your 'feminism example), the OP's desired word is probably not 'generalization' because whatever label is being used it's a generalization (that's almost always true of 'All X are Y'). The OP is looking for a word to describe the use of a word X that is related by association to the concept desired but not necessarily central or even true. I'm not sure if I've represented the OP accurately with that though. @Sam?

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: @samiam words have multiple denotations/central meanings (as well as connotations/ancillary non-defining associations). I think the examples you state are different from your title. I think the examples are faulty syllogisms based on misuse of alternate unspoken denotations.

Comment: @Mitch no, I think you're misunderstanding me then.  I'll try to come up with a more illustrative example

Comment: @Mitch I rewrote my question in hopes of simplifying it, and also in hopes of minimizing distractions.  Is it more understandable?

Comment: @Mitch: The "feminist" example no longer seems relevant, but at the time we seemed to be focusing on naming a speaker's attempt to *justify avoiding* the use of a loaded term by (incorrectly) redefining what that term means. Following the edit, we now seem to be looking for a word that simply means ***using (or avoiding) a loaded term because of its connotations, rather than its basic meaning***. Which I think is something of a lost cause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers haha. maybe the answer is 'a lost cause'.

Comment: @SamIam given your edits, I think there are two possible answers: [appeal to ambiguity](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/17/Ambiguity_Fallacy) to account for the connected use (at least must be semantically related) and [appeal to emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_emotion) which is nominally what you are asking for (and may be so in substance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a formal name or term for such a fallacy could be “[definitional retreat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies),” which Wikipedia defines as “changing the meaning of a word to deal with an objection raised against the original wording,” in less scholarly words it sounds like

> ‘Person B’ has “a position that [s/he is defending] by **[selectively
>   defining
>   terms](http://www.bettersoccermorefun.com/dwtext/defndial.htm)** to
>   meet [his/her] own needs.

(from ‘Better Soccer More Fun’[first paragraph])

Comment: close enough. .

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you're looking for is "connotation" as opposed to "denotation."

Comment: although the use of "connotation" and "denotation" would probably help me clarify my question, I don't believe that they're what I'm looking for.  What I am looking for is an idiom that describes `The phenomenon or act of confusing a word's denotation with it's connotation`

Comment: @SamIam There's no confusion, word choice is almost always intentionally motivated by connotation as much as denotation.

Comment: @Kevin That's a very succinct and clear way of describing the rhetorical value of certain words. But the question, as I understand it, was asking for an idiom describing this phenomenon.

Comment: @Yay This has nothing to do with the so called "pathetic fallacy"

Comment: @StuporUser What I meant was "Appeal to emotions fallacy". I always mix them up because of the words pathetic and emotions. Anyway, it *had* to do with it in the example "terrorists are cowardly" but after the edit it doesn't anymore, so I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

**Syllogism**
**1**. Logic A form of deductive reasoning consisting of a major premise, a minor premise, and a conclusion; for example, All humans are mortal, the major premise, I am a human, the minor premise, therefore, I am mortal, the conclusion.
**2**. Reasoning from the general to the specific; deduction.
**3**. A subtle or specious piece of reasoning.